# Server-side mailbox merge on Office 365

Tags: microsoft-office-365

I've got a bit of an issue with Office 365 - after migrating an user from an existing IMAP account it seems like their "Archive" folder conflicted with the default one provided by O365 and as a result their existing archive is now named "Archive_0".

I would like to merge this with the main "Archive" folder but the issue is that we're looking at several thousand items - so much that Mac Mail is struggling to even load it (initial download took a good 10 minutes).

Is there a way to do it server-side, though some kind of API? I'd like to do it as a batch operation instead of downloading/uploading every mail which would take ages. Preferably I would like to use my Mac but would be able to install a Windows VM if necessary.

Regards.

Comment: You can move mail around through the [Web Interface](https://Outlook.office365.com) this is always the recommended method for managing large amount of mail in a mailbox.

Comment: Honestly you can probably also just delete the current “Archive” folder and then rename the other one to match. I’m pretty sure there is nothing special about that “Archive” folder. Office 365 archives to the “Online Archive” mailbox if you enable it. Also why aren’t you using Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

You can export the content to PST, using the eDiscvoery tools. Then re-import the mail thru the Office365 Import service.